# Barrnap Bacterial rRNA Predictor script permission denied error when running Prokka

Tags: sequence-annotation, perl, bacteria, functional-annotation

I am trying to run the **Prokka annotation tool** on my linux machine and have installed **Barrnap and added it to $PATH and given the folder chmod 777 permission**. However, when running Prokka, it gives the line `Could not parse version from 'sh: 1: barrnap: Permission denied'`.

Running Barrnap solely through the command line with a valid input works fine but does not seem to work when another script calls barrnap. I have tried checking path variables and giving max permissions to barrnap and Prokka but it does not seem to change this error. Here is the full log file:

```
[15:01:28] This is prokka 1.14.6
[15:01:28] Written by Torsten Seemann <torsten.seemann@gmail.com>
[15:01:28] Homepage is https://github.com/tseemann/prokka
[15:01:28] Local time is Thu Feb 23 15:01:28 2023
[15:01:28] You are saurab
[15:01:28] Operating system is linux
[15:01:28] You have BioPerl 1.7.8
[15:01:28] System has 16 cores.
[15:01:28] Will use maximum of 8 cores.
[15:01:28] Annotating as >>> Bacteria <<<
[15:01:28] Generating locus_tag from 'jobs/NC_004556.faa' contents.
[15:01:28] Setting --locustag ECJHPMJE from MD5 ec31963ed5d3d76e28501fa7e45ca273
[15:01:28] Creating new output folder: PROKKA_02232023
[15:01:28] Running: mkdir -p PROKKA_02232023
[15:01:28] Using filename prefix: PROKKA_02232023.XXX
[15:01:28] Setting HMMER_NCPU=1
[15:01:28] Writing log to: PROKKA_02232023/PROKKA_02232023.log
[15:01:28] Command: /home/saurab/BIOIN/basys2-app/sub_programs/prokka/bin/prokka jobs/NC_004556.faa
[15:01:28] Appending to PATH: /home/saurab/BIOIN/basys2-app/sub_programs/prokka/bin/../binaries/linux
[15:01:28] Appending to PATH: /home/saurab/BIOIN/basys2-app/sub_programs/prokka/bin/../binaries/linux/../common
[15:01:28] Appending to PATH: /home/saurab/BIOIN/basys2-app/sub_programs/prokka/bin
[15:01:28] Looking for 'aragorn' - found /home/saurab/BIOIN/phastest-app/sub_programs/aragorn
[15:01:28] Determined aragorn version is 001002 from 'ARAGORN v1.2   Dean Laslett'
[15:01:28] Looking for 'barrnap' - found /home/saurab/BIOIN/phastest-app/sub_programs/barrnap
[15:01:28] Coult not parse version from 'sh: 1: barrnap: Permission denied'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -l /home/saurab/BIOIN/phastest-app/sub_programs/barrnap`. You say you set the directory to 777 but what about the actual script/executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to run `prokka` from within `conda` by simply downloading [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/user-guide/install/download.html) then

```
conda create --name prokka
conda activate prokka
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults prokka
prokka --help
prokka --version
prokka mycontigs.fa # running prokka
```

You could always perform a

```
chmod 700 /home/saurab/BIOIN/phastest-app/sub_programs/barrnap
```

or some variant like `chmod 500 ...`

or possibly using a recursive `chmod -R 500` that sort of thing. Eventually it will work.

**However**, it strikes me you are installing `prokka` outside any virtual environment such as `conda` or `brew` and I would not do that personally, because you are giving significant permissions to the algorithm.

`conda` (or `brew`) will sort out all the permission needed and there's no need to do anything with `chmod` stuff.

Good luck with the annotation.