# PROKKA setupdb / cmpress error

Tags: sequence-annotation, database, errors

I am trying to run --setupdb in Prokka, but I'm getting this error that I can't seem to find the answer for.

When I run
`prokka --setupdb`

I get

```
[18:57:31] Determined cmpress version is 001001 from '# INFERNAL 1.1.4 (Dec 2020)'
[18:57:31] Pressing CM database: /home/carol/.local/lib/prokka/db/cm/Viruses
[18:57:31] Running: cmpress \/home\/carol\/\.local\/lib\/prokka\/db\/cm\/Viruses

Error: File existence/permissions problem in trying to open CM file /home/carol/.local/lib/prokka/db/cm/Viruses.
CM file /home/carol/.local/lib/prokka/db/cm/Viruses not found (nor an .i1m binary of it)

[18:57:31] Could not run command: cmpress \/home\/carol\/\.local\/lib\/prokka\/db\/cm\/Viruses
```

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: This is a known problem with Prokka and was previously answered here https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/20620/barrnap-bacterial-rrna-predictor-script-permission-denied-error-when-running-pro/20621#20621
Please let us know if this is okay, then we can close the question.